# Can't open some programs like Telegram, through batch

Tags: batch

For some reason, I'm having trouble opening Telegram through the use of a batch script.

[image]

[image]

The above script, just opens the following CMD window:
[image]

Tried searching here and there, but to no avail of course...

Comment: Are you certain Telegram is installed in Roaming? That is not correct. Try launching Telegram from Program Files or Program Files (X86).

Comment: @John thank you for commenting! Yep, just checked and added a additional image to the thread

Comment: I am not sure. That seems to be the telegram folder. Windows Apps are in a hidden folder in Program Files. I wonder if using the Roaming folder is preventing a batch command start.

Comment: @John Hm, I did inspect the Program Files, but I happen to only have Telegram inside of the Roaming folder ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `/D` with `start` to specify the path of the folder containing the program**

When the path of the program contain space, you need to use Quotes to interpret it completely. However, the first quoted string is used as console title according to `start` documentation.

Source : https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

You should use `/D` to specify the quoted path of the folder, followed by the program name :

```
start /D "C:\users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\telegram desktop" telegram.exe
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you so much!